# Attempting to load WGT on watch, have -19 error

Tags: watch, tizen

I'm loading a watch face using Tizen and the Web IDE. Everything runs fine on the Emulator.
When I load it on my watch (obviously I sign it with a Samsung Certificate) I get the below errors. I've validated with the Javascript validator and all is fine. I can load a templated 4.0 app however not with my built app.

The second log would suggest it's a C / C++ issue however this is above my level of programming, difficult to fix a C issue if I'm coding Javascript.

```
WARNING: Your data are to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could be read by others.
pushed              MoodTracker_4.wgt   100%         14MB        1874KB/s
1 file(s) pushed. 0 file(s) skipped.
C:\Users\itadmin\Downloads\MoodTracker_4.wgt   2223KB/s (15506333 bytes in 6.809s)
path is /home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/MoodTracker_4.wgt
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[] key[start] val[install]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[] key[error] val[-19]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[] key[end] val[fail]
processing result : Parsing error [-19] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [2409]ms
```

Log:

```
07-04 16:02:14.701 : Error / CAPI_MEDIA_CONTROLLER ( 2943 : 2943 ) : media_controller_main.c: __mc_main_check_connection(37) > [31m[No-error] Timer is Called but there is working Process, connection_cnt = 3[0m
07-04 16:02:17.911 : Debug / APP_INSTALLERS ( 4381 : 4381 ) : [0m| DEBUG   |[0m                           : pkgmgr_signal.cc:192                 : Success to send pkgmgr signal PKGID= KEY=error VALUE=-19
07-04 16:02:17.921 : Debug / APP_INSTALLERS ( 4381 : 4381 ) : [0m| DEBUG   |[0m                           : pkgmgr_signal.cc:217                 : Success to send pkgmgr signal USER=5001 PKGID= KEY=error VALUE=-19
07-04 16:02:17.941 : Info / PKGMGR_SERVER ( 4377 : 4377 ) : pkgmgr-server.c: __signal_handler(381) > [__signal_handler:381] backend[wgt][4381] exit with error
07-04 16:02:18.031 : Warning / APPTRAY ( 2778 : 2778 ) : AppTrayPkgHandler.cpp: _clientListen(145) >  pkgmgr request [error:-19]
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have signed the wgt in the proper way?

The watch has to be identified by your TizenStudio/signingManager before you sign it, and then being able to upload it.

Do check all descriptions on Signing in the Samsung Developer Q&A Forum.
Or the Developer Testing parts on Samsung Developer.

It is a mess getting it all up and running for the first time, but it works!